# Ways to create Spark grammar from SAS job using ANTLR

Tags: sas, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to use ANTLR for parsing SAS jobs and creating parser based on that.

I am using SAS grammar from https://github.com/xueqilsj/sas-grammar and using ANTLR for parsing and lexical analyzer. I am also using the link provided here: https://shijinglu.wordpress.com/2015/01/22/write-a-primitive-sas-grammar-in-antlr4/ .

Just to clarify, every SAS gramamr is of the format:

```
grammar AbortStmt; 

import CommonLexerRules; 

abort_main
 : (abort_stmt)* EOF 
 ; 

abort_stmt
 : ABORT (ABEND | CANCEL (file_spec)? | RETURN )? INT? NOLIST? ';'
 ; 

file_spec
 : STRINGLITERAL 
 ;
```

and I am having problem with the import statement. After I have created the autogenerated class using ANTLR , I am getting the following error:

1. Can't load AbortStmtBaseListener.class as lexer or parser.
2. Can’t import the Rules.

I  am limited by the SAS imports that are defined in the grammar file(as every grammar file has a defined import). Any other ways to parse the grammar files and create decision trees?

Comment: Just to clarify,every SAS gramamr is of the format:  grammar AbortStmt;

import CommonLexerRules;

abort_main
 : (abort_stmt)* EOF
 ;
abort_stmt
 : ABORT (ABEND | CANCEL (file_spec)? | RETURN )? INT? NOLIST? ';';
 
file_spec: STRINGLITERAL ;  and I am having problem with the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

Once you run ANTLR on the grammar, the result is a group of `.java` files.  Did you then run `javac` to compile them into `.class` files?  That might account for your problem.  I've forgotten to do that before.  After that you can run TestRig to see your tokens or the graphical representation of your parse.

Comment: Thanks. Actually my SAS grammars have dependent grammars which needs to be included. I did that and created the Listener etc *.java files. But after that I am not able to create the decision tree. I need to create the tree to convert it into Spark grammar.